# Symfony 2 SQLSTATE Connection refused

Tags: database, symfony

I have a problem with connecting my database online.
My site is hosted on one server, and connects to a remote database that is on another server.
But it sends me the following error:

> SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] Connection refused Error

I did, however, put the exact connection information .. I do not understand why the connection is refused ..

parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
database_host: **.**.**.**
database_port: 3306
database_name: zip
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_user: root
database_password: null
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 
mailer_user: 
mailer_password: 
secret: d87fdb6ecf4089df33360b187388e33c34e12f85
```

I thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user/password are the right ones. You can use the `mysql` command line cli to try to connect.

Comment: I managed to connect to the database with putty with the password and the identifier that I entered in the parameters.yml. and I made a connection to that same base in a java program, and it works. I do not understand what's wrong with symfony